# phpstorm, import VCS file(local history) from phpstorm2017.2 to phpstorm2019.2

Tags: windows, installation, phpstorm

I want import or restore localhistory(VCS) files from phpstorm 2017.2 to phpstorm 2019.2

I have "changes.storageData" file from old phpstorm, last time I changed all directory of this contents of file from H:/ to C:/ after reinstalling phpstorm 2017.2, and now after removing old Windows and installing new Windows 8.1 , I installed phpstorm 2019.2 and In addition to doing the previous thing I said(change contents from H:/ to C:/) , changed directory name of phpstorm2017.2 to phpstorm2019.2 and replace the file, but doesnt work and I cant see history of changes in VCS->LocalHistory

**How can I restore LocalHistory data from phpstorm2017.2 to phpstorm2019.2?**

```
(I cant install newer version of PhpStorm now)
```

picture of chanages:

[Picture #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQV9o.jpg)

[Picture #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmvqa.jpg)

Comment: **Nobody knows ???**

Comment: why, nobody knows? '_'

Comment: Ask phpstorm team.

Comment: @Toto I do it, but doesnt answer anybody yet.